# The integration of $f$ against any open set $U$ is less than or equal to $Bm(U)$

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to think about the following problem:

> If the integration of $f \in L^{\mathbb R}$ against any open set $U$ is less than or equal to $Bm(U)$, then $f$ itself should be less than or equal to $B$.

What I tried: For continuous $f$ this is easy. For $f$ that is not continuous, I tried to approximate the set $\{f > B\}$ with an open set, which seems to be a dead end. Another thing I have tried is to approximate $f$ with a continuous function, but it does not work either. There is a sign problem there writing it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lebesgue Differentiation Theorem gives the result (almost everywhere) immediately.

OK, here's a more elementary proof for $f$ bounded. Clearly we may localize to assume $f$ has compact support. Then we can uniformly approximate $f$ by a continuous function. Precisely, for any $\epsilon > 0$, take continuous $g$ with $||f-g||_\infty <\epsilon$. Then $g$ will satisfy $\int_U g \le (B+\epsilon)|U|$ for all open sets $U$ and thus $g \le B+\epsilon$ a.e.. So, $f \le B+2\epsilon$ a.e. This holds for all $\epsilon > 0$.

Comment: Brilliant!!!! Is there more natural way to think about it though?

Comment: This is very very natural for me.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I should say more elementary rather than natural then.

Comment: The point is that Lebesgue Differentiation Theorem tells us that measurable functions are similar to continuous functions in an integration sense. Rather than all points $f(y)$ for $y$ close to $x$ needing to be close to $f(x)$, LDT says that $\frac{1}{|B|}\int_B f(y)$ is close to $f(x)$ for small $B$ containing $x$.